# Cakephp belongs to with null id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need to find all rows which userId is `1` or `null`, but cake generate the follow:

```
    SELECT `SysMenu`.*
      FROM `sigepar_softpc`.`sys_permissions` AS `SysPermission`
 LEFT JOIN `sigepar_softpc`.`sys_users` AS `SysUser`
        ON (`SysPermission`.`user_id` = `SysUser`.`id`)
     WHERE `SysPermission`.`user_id`
        IN (1, NULL)
```

I think the problem is the 4th line, because of

> `SysPermission`.`user_id` = `SysUser`.`id`

I do the follow inside my controller:

```
$sysPermissions = ClassRegistry::init('SysPermission')->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'SysPermission.user_id' => array('1', null)
        ),
        'fields' => array('SysMenu.*')
    )
);
```

How I can get all rows, with association allowing a ID or `NULL`?

Comment: Do you have User with null id, or some of your permission has no user?

Comment: Some of my permissions has no user. Permissions with user `null` is a guest permission.

Comment: Guest user do not perform login actions or at least they shouldn't (cause they guests, not members). So I do not understand why you perform all these queries at all while you can set-up Auth component and let all unauthorized users access to specific actions.

Comment: @xeranas it is because I want my users setup all permissions, and not do a `$this->Auth->allow()` at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$sysPermissions = ClassRegistry::init('SysPermission')->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array('SysPermission.user_id' => 1, 'SysPermission.user_id' => null)
        ),
        'fields' => array('SysMenu.*')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to put null in the IN operator. Its expects values and null is not a value. So You really have to put the OR with the null to get the desired result.

you must try this code as Davor Lozic mentioned:

```
$sysPermissions = ClassRegistry::init('SysPermission')->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array('SysPermission.user_id' => array('your values'), 'SysPermission.user_id' => null)
        ),
        'fields' => array('SysMenu.*')
    )
);
```